# run userscript on content after $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I am doing a get request on a page ie: url.com, then checking whether something exists on it.  If the info I am looking for exists I open a blank page and put the contents of the get request onto the blank page via document.write.

Tampermonkey doesn't recognize that a script needs to be run when I update it via win.history.pushState, so nothing gets executed.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
$.get(url,
    function(data)
    {
        var win=window.open('',"_blank");
        win.history.pushState({ 'page_id': 1}, "newpage", "https://www.url.com/stuff/");    //this line doesn't work
        with(win.document){
            open();
            write(data);
            close();

        }
    }
)
```

Comment: _"open a blank page and put the contents of the get request onto the blank page via document.write."_ What is expected result of `win.history.pushState({ 'page_id': 1}, "newpage", "https://www.url.com/stuff/");` ?

Comment: I was expecting it to set the url of the new window.  Then when Tampermonkey checks which scripts are active on the page it will find the scripts that match ie:  `// @include        https://www.url.com/stuff/` , and run that external script correctly.